# Is there any way to filter folders/directories by name in windows?

Tags: windows, directory, copy, move, directory-structure

Is there any way to filter folders by Name in Windows?

Let's suppose I have 100 or 200 folders with different names in the directory.
Now I have a list of specific folder names that are in the folders and I want to filter/move those listed name folders to another directory.

**In an easy word I want to copy/move listed folder names to another folder/directory.**

How can I do that with any software in bulk? I am searching for it but I can't find any software to do this task for me. I can manually move the folder one by one but it's so time-consuming when I have hundreds of folders.

I am currently using XCOPY GUI software but in this software, I have to first filter the path exception folder before I get my final result.

**Example:**

Main Dir contains

- 1st folder
- 2nd folder
- 3rd folder
- 4th folder

and so on ...

I have a list of names in my notepad which folders I want to copy or move.

3rd folder,
4th folder

Final Dir:

- 3rd folder
- 4th folder

How can I do that in bilk using any software or any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, you can use methods in the `Files` class, or instances of `File`.
For example, `Files.move()` might help. If you're using an IDE, type stuff that might be right, like `Files.move()`, and suggestions will pop up that might lead you down the right path. Also, you can look at the documentation. I am currently scraping the web and creating and filing files, so I know about this somewhat, although not specifically about moving folders rather than files. I'm using Java on a MacBook, so that might influence how relevant my suggestions are to you depending on what you're using.
Basically, look at the documentation for your language. You hopefully won't need any external libraries since moving folders should be a basic task.